# Override the arg in dockerfile

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a docker file which has a user directive

```
ARG UID=1000
ARG GID=1000

USER ${UID}:${GID}
```

I try to run the docker compose file using the command

```
docker-compose run -u 501:20 --no-deps --rm dev go test -mod=readonly -race ./...
```

I would like to replace the UID and GID in the dockerfile to be with the arguments provided in the run command.

Could someone please help me to realise this?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this without rebuilding the Docker image from its source.

```sh
docker build --build-arg UID=501 --build-arg GID=20 -t dev:uid-501 .
docker run --rm dev:uid-501 ...
```

Correspondingly, passing a specific user ID into a Docker image's `ARG` isn't really a best practice, especially if you expect that uid to match a specific host uid: it means you need to repeat recompilation steps every time a different user wants to run the image, and users frequently won't be able to use an unmodified image from Docker Hub or another repository.

A typical setup I've used is to leave the application source code or built binaries owned by the root user, and non-writable.  If the application does have persistent state, put that in its own dedicated directory.  In the Dockerfile, create a non-root user with a default user ID and make the directory owned by that user.  If you need to use a bind-mounted host directory with this, you can `docker run -u $(id -u)` to have the container take on the host user ID.

```sh
# do not pass ARG UID=...

# do create some non-root user with default settings
RUN adduser --system --no-create-home appuser

# still as root, run your normal build process
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN ./install.sh

# create a data directory owned by the non-root user
ENV DATA_DIR=/data # recognized by the application
RUN mkdir "$DATA_DIR" && chown appuser "$DATA_DIR"

# switch to the non-root user only to run the container
USER appuser
CMD ["./my_app"]
```

```sh
# Run the container with its default temporary storage
docker run myimage

# Run the container with its default user but a named volume for storage
docker run -v data:/data myimage

# Run the container with a host user and a bind-mounted data directory
docker run -u $(id -u):$(id -g) -v "$PWD/data:/data" myimage
```